# What does it take to get an app featured on data.gov?

Tags: data.gov

I created a website using open data and I would love to see it featured on [data.gov/applications](http://www.data.gov/applications). Are there requirements to be featured on data.gov? Is there somewhere where I can submit my application for consideration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [Contact page](http://www.data.gov/contact#request) at Data.gov you can select an option in the form to Submit an Application.

Requirements for the apps listed are [also posted](http://www.data.gov/applications). Those apps must:

- "Use open government data from the United States
- Be accessible, vetted, and available
- Be, for the majority, free and do not require registration to use"

Many of the apps have come out of businesses using open government data (see examples at the [Open Data 500](http://www.opendata500.com/)), city and Federal hack-a-thons, or [challenges](http://www.challenge.gov/list/) issued by the Federal government.  But, anyone is welcome to submit their app or service to Data.gov.